# Consuming non-normalized data with the Knockout Mapping Plug-In

Tags: javascript, json, mapping, knockout.js, denormalized

I have a REST service that returns a collection that contains non-
normalized data. For example, it might look something like this:

```
root
.
root:CollectionItem[0].alpha
root:CollectionItem[0].beta
root:CollectionItem[0].zappa
.
root:CollectionItem[1].alpha
root:CollectionItem[1].children[0].MoonUnit
root:CollectionItem[1].children[1].Dweezil
root:CollectionItem[1].zappa
.
root:CollectionItem[2].alpha
root:CollectionItem[2].beta
root:CollectionItem[2].zappa
```

What's the best strategy for using the Mapping PlugIn with non-normalized JSON data like this? The problem is that the PlugIn seems to use CollectionItem[0] as a template, but when I foreach through a result, Knockout is blowing up when I try to read root.CollectionItem[1].beta (which doesn't exist).

**EDIT #1**: I guess Knockout isn't as popular as I thought... This question seems destined for a Tumbleweed Award. :-(

**EDIT #2**: Got a workable answer on the Knockout Forum http://groups.google.com/group/knockoutjs/browse_thread/thread/6705c222481c7b75#, so I don't have to worry about another Tumbleweed Award! :-)

Comment: Correct tagging helps avoid tumbleweeds.  :)

Comment: Thanks for fixing up my Wyoming-inspired tagging. (I was born in Wyoming, and there are a lot of tumbleweeds there!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got an answer from someone named **NTB** on the Knockout JS forum. Here's his solution on JS fiddle in case anyone is interested. Hate to answer my own question, but it is what it is.

http://jsfiddle.net/PxeyY/

Here's his summary:

"I have
sometimes manually "massaged" the data before calling the mapper, or
created a dummy shell object that has all the possible properties set to
null (or [] in the case of arrays) -- then use $.extend(dummy, real) to
create something .fromJS() can work with.  You'd have to iterate through
the array with that pattern, but that's my $.02 anyway.

"Would like to hear cleaner solutions myself too though."

Comment: The solution proposed by NTB (see the jsfiddle link) actually works brilliantly for denormalized data. And when I want to send the deserialize the model and send it back up to a RESTful API, I only need to recursively walk through the model and 'delete' all empty arrays and nodes with null values.